# Multiple imputation for predictor and outcome variables

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation

I want to evaluate the impact of some risk and protective factors (predictor) on different health variables (outcome), and report descriptive measures of the health variables. I have missing data on both the predictor AND the outcome variables. I was wondering: 1)if I should impute both the predictor and the outcome variables
2) if yes, whether i should include the both the outcome and predictor variables as imputed AND imputer variables for the imputation (mice).

I have found contradictory information regarding this in the literature.

Thank you in advance.